# How to use Putty for SSH connection to Ubuntu installed as an app from Microsoft Store

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

My question is about Accessing ubuntu app from putty.

I have Installed ubuntu command line in my Windows 10 System .
Here is the Link :-
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

I want to use this installed ubuntu from putty SSH.
I have done this before but when it was installed inside a virtual machine.
But this time ubuntu is installed as an Microsoft Store app.

This is the `ipconfig` command result for my windows machine (Real PC)

[Result of `ipconfig`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2haU.png)

And This is the result of `ifconfig` on ubuntu (Installed as an App)

[Result of `ifconfig`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYORe.png)

Please help me in connecting (logging in ) to the ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand this app, there is no VM to ssh into. It use the Windows subsystem for Linux. In other words, you can't access it from putty. It's sorta like asking how do you access cmd.exe from putty. Hope that helps.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Answer (score 0):

You need to try to install `sshd`
You can do it by typing `apt install sshd` .
Then go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and configure in a way you want. 
After that execute `sudo service sshd restart` or simply restart you Ubuntu subsystem to make configuration operational.
You can find more about sshd_config here:
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd_config/

Eddited: 
Your question answered here:
https://superuser.com/q/1111591